# Parsing Geometry to Latitude, Longitude is failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table of locations with Latitude and Longitude values.

```
Loc_Nm || geocode_latitude || geocode_longitude
   A   ||    43.43044      ||    -80.0910793
   W   ||    43.9114523    ||    -80.0911329
   X   ||    43.9209011    ||    -80.091323
   Y   ||    43.9083203    ||    -80.0913039
   Z   ||    43.914577     ||    -80.091198
```

I have a geometry table with area names (shown below) which has been converted from Shapefile through ogr2ogr.

[image: Table2]
I need to group the Table1 locations into specific regions as per Table2. I am using a query utilizing below-mentioned snippet.

```
select * from MyDB.dbo.Spatial_Data s, MyDB.dbo.geocodes_raw g 
where ogr_geometry.STContains(geometry::Parse('POINT(' + CAST(g.geocode_longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(g.geocode_latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'))=1;
```

But, it is failing with below-given error.

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 7 of the input. The input has ).
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeDouble()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Parse(SqlString s)
.
```

What is possibly wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `g.geocode_latitude` or `g.geocode_longitude` value that is empty or not valid as coordinate.

Try doing the following you will see that it fails with the same error message:

```
SELECT geometry::Parse('POINT(43 )') -- Missing coordinate
```

To solve, just filter where both coordinates are actually informed and correct (expression depends on data type). You can use `TRY_PARSE` for that matter.

---

To check error lines you can do a quick check with:

```
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    MyDB.dbo.geocodes_raw AS T
WHERE
    TRY_PARSE(T.geocode_longitude AS FLOAT) IS NULL OR
    TRY_PARSE(T.geocode_latitude AS FLOAT) IS NULL
```

Or a more thorough (but slower) with a cursor:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ErrorGeocodes') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ErrorGeocodes

CREATE TABLE #ErrorGeocodes (
    geocode_longitude VARCHAR(200),
    geocode_latitude VARCHAR(200))

DECLARE @c_geocode_longitude VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @c_geocode_latitude VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE GeocodeCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T.geocode_longitude,
        T.geocode_latitude
    FROM
        MyDB.dbo.geocodes_raw AS T

OPEN GeocodeCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM GeocodeCursor INTO @c_geocode_longitude, @c_geocode_latitude

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @v_GeometryTest GEOMETRY = 
            GEOMETRY::Parse('POINT(' + @c_geocode_longitude + ' ' + @c_geocode_latitude + ')')

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        INSERT INTO #ErrorGeocodes (
            geocode_latitude,
            geocode_longitude)
        SELECT
            geocode_latitude = @c_geocode_latitude,
            geocode_longitude = @c_geocode_longitude

    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM GeocodeCursor INTO @c_geocode_longitude, @c_geocode_latitude

END

CLOSE GeocodeCursor
DEALLOCATE GeocodeCursor

SELECT * FROM #ErrorGeocodes
```

Comment: I used the same table of geocodes for another set of geometry table and that works out fine with the same query. I guess it's not about the geocodes table but something is different about the ogr_geometry column for the Table2.

Comment: Try doing a `SELECT` of the `geometry::Parse()` of just your `MyDB.dbo.geocodes_raw` table (without joining) and see if it fails. The error message is pretty clear tho.

Comment: I see what you mean. Can you please help me to filter out the incorrect coordinates? I can't figure out how to use TRY_PARSE for my purpose.

Comment: @RAVIBANSAL included validation queries.

Comment: Thanks, @EzLo. I removed the records failing the TRY_PARSE NULL validation, from the geocodes table. But, still my query `select * from MyDB.dbo.Spatial_Data s, MyDB.dbo.geocodes_raw g 
where ogr_geometry.STContains(geometry::Parse('POINT(' + CAST(g.geocode_longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(g.geocode_latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'))=1;` returns zero records.

Comment: @RAVIBANSAL make sure that you are generating the point with the coordinates in the correct order (you are using longitude first, latitude second). Try calculating the STDistance instead of STContains and see if the results seem logical for your data.